# Селектор jquery: элемент, сразу после которого есть нужный текст

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Здравствуйте, есть несколько элементов с классом .class!
После некоторых из них есть ul c id="tree".
Как выбрать те элементы .class, после которых сразу идет подобный ul?
Если ul идет, к примеру, через строчку, то этот элемент уже брать нельзя.

Так можно вообще выбрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID элемента должен быть уникальным. Использовать несколько ul с id="tree" неправильно.
Лучше используйте класс.

С учетом этого замечания, решение будет таким:

```
$('ul.tree').prev().filter('.class');
```

*Выбери элементы, идущие сразу перед ul.tree. Оставь в выборке только элементы с классом .class*

**[Ссылка на пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/qUGb4/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
.tree + .class
```

http://jquery-docs.ru/selectors/

Comment: @Fuad Cavadov, нужно выбрать .class, которые идут не ПОСЛЕ .tree, а ДО него. Такое решение не подойдет.